# How to get employees who complete 5 years in organization on quarterly basis

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the employees who completed their 5,10,15,20 etc years.
I want to retrieve data in quarterly basis 
so I have added switch statement in where clause

```
declare @CurrentDate date

set @CurrentDate=GETDATE() ;

select EmployeeID,FirstName+''+isnull(MiddleName,'')+''+LastName as EmployeeName,JoiningDate,DATEDIFF(year, isnull(JoiningDate,''),getdate()) Experience

 from HRIS.dbo.EmpMaster
 where 
 ActiveFlag=1 and
CASE
    WHEN  DATEPART(quarter, getdate()) =1 and month(JoiningDate) BETWEEN 1 and 3 then 1
    WHEN  DATEPART(quarter, getdate()) =2 and month(JoiningDate) BETWEEN 4 and 6 then 1
    WHEN  DATEPART(quarter, getdate()) =3 and month(JoiningDate) BETWEEN 7 and 9 then 1
    WHEN  DATEPART(quarter, getdate()) =4 and month(JoiningDate) BETWEEN 10 and 12 then 1
    else 0
    END
 and  DATEDIFF(year, isnull(JoiningDate,''),@CurrentDate)%5=0 and Year(JoiningDate)!=2019
```

I am getting error as below

```
Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.
```

I understood the error is because the case in where clause is not returning a boolean.

how to write the switch case so that it returns a boolean

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of CASE expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . why not simplify this?

```
WHERE ActiveFlag = 1 AND
      DATEPART(quarter, getdate()) = DATEPART(quarter, JoiningDate)
```

This just seems much simpler.

Your problem would be fixed by adding `= 1` after the `END`.  But I don't recommend that approach.